# Can we update record of addressbook?

Tags: iphone

I want to update record of addressbook. I searched for it but I have not got any particular solution for this. I am able to access addressbook but after changing phone number or any field I want to update it. Please give some code example......

Comment: Got the solution. We can update the record in the addressbook programmatically....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit a record using this function :

```
bool ABRecordSetValue (
   ABRecordRef record,
   ABPropertyID property,
   CFTypeRef value,
   CFErrorRef *error
);
```

For more information, visit this link : [ABRecord Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007096)